# Excel sorting by values in a column then by dates in a different column

Tags: excel

Going to start off saying that I don't know much about excel, that is why I am here so I'll explain the best I can.

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is a list of people that lists hours they work. For example,

Column A is Name
Column B is Hours
Column C is Hire Date

Column B has the =sum formula to add values as they are updated as values are entered into other columns for each row of names.

I would love to know if it's possible and how to do it where the =sum stays the same but then Column B is sorted numerically then if any of the values in Column B are the same those are sorted by hire date.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks

I don't even really know where to begin on this other than knowing the =sum formula part of what I am looking to have done.

Answer (score 0):

You could format your data to be a table from the 'Home' tab then go to the 'Table Design' tab and tick the 'total row' option and the 'filter button' options. Now you will automatically have your =SUM at the bottom and you can use the drop down arrows to filter each row as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There must be no blank columns between Columns A,B,C and the columns with the hours.

Click anywhere in your data
On the Home tab click Sort & Filter > Filter (this will add drop down arrows to your data)
On the Home tab click Sort & Filter > Custom Sort

In the pop up window, Sort by Hours Largest to Smallest, then by Hire Date Newest to Oldest (or whatever order you want).

Any time you update the hours, you can re-apply the sorting rules by clicking Sort & Filter > Reapply, or right-click in the data > Filter > Reapply

[image]